# Paste a list to a vector, repeating the list for each vector level

Tags: r, list, combinations, apply, paste

I want to accomplish the following task without having to enter a `for` loop, but rather in a single `apply()` command.

I have a list `a` that I want to repeat `N` times, where `N` is the length of vector `b`, pasting each repetition of `a` to an element of `b`.

So far I have done the following MWE:

```
var <- paste("var", 1:4, sep="")
treat <- c("A","B")
spec <- paste("sp", 1:3, sep="")
a <- combn(var, 2, simplify = FALSE)#this 6 times, for each treatment and species
b <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(treat, spec), sep='.'))
a1 <- lapply(a, paste, b[1], sep='.')
a2 <- lapply(a, paste, b[2], sep='.')
a3 <- lapply(a, paste, b[3], sep='.')
a4 <- lapply(a, paste, b[4], sep='.')
a5 <- lapply(a, paste, b[5], sep='.')
a6 <- lapply(a, paste, b[6], sep='.')
a.final <- c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
a.final
```

It would be optimal if I could paste `b` before `a`.

Note my starting points are 3 vectors: `var`, `treat` and `spec`, so feel free to change anything from that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**  We can accomplish this without any `apply()` loops at all.  Let's `unlist()` the `a` list, `paste()` it to the replicated `b` values, then `relist()` it based on the replicated `a` lists. Try this:

```
aa <- relist(
    paste(unlist(a), rep(b, each=sum(lengths(a))), sep="."), 
    rep.int(a, length(b))
)
```

Check:

```
identical(aa, a.final)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Option 1 with `b` before `a`:** Now, to put the `b` values out front, just swap the arguments in the `paste()` call:

```
relist(
    paste(rep(b, each=sum(lengths(a))), unlist(a), sep = "."),  
    rep.int(a, length(b))
)
```

**Option 2:**  This option does use an `apply()` loop.  Here we use `Map()` to do one-to-one pasting.

```
ra <- rep(a, length(b))
aa2 <- Map(paste, ra, relist(rep(b, each=sum(lengths(a))), ra), sep = ".")
```

Check:

```
identical(aa2, a.final)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Option 2 with `b` before `a`:**  Just swap the unnamed `Map()` arguments that are passed to `paste()`.

```
ra <- rep(a, length(b))
Map(paste, relist(rep(b, each=sum(lengths(a))), ra), ra, sep = ".")
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Staying close to OP's approach, this can be solved with nested `lapply()` using anonymous functions:

```
unlist(lapply(b, function(x) lapply(a, function(y) paste(x, y, sep = "."))), 
       recursive = FALSE)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "A.sp1.var1" "A.sp1.var2"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "A.sp1.var1" "A.sp1.var3"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "A.sp1.var1" "A.sp1.var4"
>
> ...
>
> [[34]]
> [1] "B.sp3.var2" "B.sp3.var3"
>
> [[35]]
> [1] "B.sp3.var2" "B.sp3.var4"
>
> [[36]]
> [1] "B.sp3.var3" "B.sp3.var4"
> ```

Note, `b` is pasted in front of `a`. `unlist()` is required to flatten out top level list.

To verify approach is working (`a` in front of `b` to compare with `a.final`):

```
identical(a.final,
          unlist(lapply(b, function(x) lapply(a, function(y) paste(y, x, sep = "."))), 
                 recursive = FALSE))
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely different approach which creates the labels from scratch and returns them in a 36 rows x 2 columns data.table instead of a list with 36 vectors of length 2:

```
library(data.table)
# cross join of treat, spec, var. Note, full labels will be created in sprintf() below
DT <- CJ(LETTERS[1:2], 1:3, 1:4)
# non equi join as replacement of combn()
DT[DT, on = .(V1, V2, V3 > V3), nomatch = 0L,
   # create labels
   .(sprintf("%s.sp%s.var%i", V1, V2, V3), 
     sprintf("%s.sp%s.var%i", V1, V2, x.V3))]
```

> ```
>             V1         V2
>  1: A.sp1.var1 A.sp1.var2
>  2: A.sp1.var1 A.sp1.var3
>  3: A.sp1.var1 A.sp1.var4
>  4: A.sp1.var2 A.sp1.var3
>  5: A.sp1.var2 A.sp1.var4
>  6: A.sp1.var3 A.sp1.var4
>  7: A.sp2.var1 A.sp2.var2
> ...
> 29: B.sp2.var2 B.sp2.var4
> 30: B.sp2.var3 B.sp2.var4
> 31: B.sp3.var1 B.sp3.var2
> 32: B.sp3.var1 B.sp3.var3
> 33: B.sp3.var1 B.sp3.var4
> 34: B.sp3.var2 B.sp3.var3
> 35: B.sp3.var2 B.sp3.var4
> 36: B.sp3.var3 B.sp3.var4
>             V1         V2
> ```